# Combine all elements of n lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

there are a lot of questions and answers about combining and merging lists in python but I have not found a way to create a full combination of all elements.

If I had a list of lists like the following:

```
data_small = [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'] ]
data_big = [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['u','v','w'], ['x','y','z'] ]
```

How can I get a list of lists with all combinations?
For `data_small` this should be:

```
[ [a,b,c], [d,b,c], [a,b,f], [a,e,c],
  [d,e,c], [d,b,f], [a,e,f], [d,e,f], ... ]
```

This should also work for an arbitrary number of lists *of the same length* like `data_big`.

I am pretty sure there is a fancy itertools solution for this, right?

Comment: Will the letters across different sublists always be unique?

Comment: Specifications unclear. Define combination.

Comment: There should be 20 combinations and you've only shown 8 so that list either isn't complete or there's rules that aren't specified. Which is it?

Comment: Was just going to write that: 6 over 3 = 20.

Comment: I understood what they meant; I think: Not combinations in the usual sense, but replacing each position in a sublist with the items in the corresponding position in other sublists. With that definition, the outcome makes sense.

Comment: Thanks L3viathan! That's what I meant. I am sorry if my question was not clear enough! Although I cannot understand 4 downvotes on that.
However, 6 over 3 = 20 combinations was intended.

Comment: That's contradictory. If @L3viathan is correct then you will only have 8 combinations but if you just want all combinations then you will have 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I deciphered the question:

```
def so_called_combs(data):
    for sublist in data:
        for sbl in data:
            if sbl==sublist:
                yield sbl
                continue
            for i in range(len(sublist)):
                c = sublist[:]
                c[i] = sbl[i]
                yield c
```

This returns the required list, if I understood it correctly:

For every list in the data, every element is replaced (but only one at a time) with the corresponding element (same position) in each of the other lists.

For `data_big`, this returns:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'f'],
 ['u', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'v', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'w'], ['x', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'y', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'z'], ['a', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'b', 'f'],
 ['d', 'e', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['u', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'v', 'f'], 
 ['d', 'e', 'w'], ['x', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'y', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'z'],
 ['a', 'v', 'w'], ['u', 'b', 'w'], ['u', 'v', 'c'], ['d', 'v', 'w'],
 ['u', 'e', 'w'], ['u', 'v', 'f'], ['u', 'v', 'w'], ['x', 'v', 'w'],
 ['u', 'y', 'w'], ['u', 'v', 'z'], ['a', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'b', 'z'],
 ['x', 'y', 'c'], ['d', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'e', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'f'],
 ['u', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'v', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'w'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! "so_called_combs" :D How would you call it?

Comment: @coroner I don't know, what do you use it for? I wouldn't call it combinations, because that means something else (see `itertools.combinations`)

Comment: This doesn't give all the "combinations" it's missing `['a','e','w']` and 23 more

Comment: @SirParselot I interpreted it as only ever replacing one element. Since I don't know what they really want, I could only guess. But good point.

Comment: Well between the two of our answers I think we covered all angles

Comment: @SirParselot Why `['a', 'b', 'i']`? `i` isn't in any of the input lists.

Comment: Forget I mentioned it. I added that one in

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do using itertools permutations and chain function. You also need to check if the indexes line up and are all the same length, and whether there is more than one element being replaced

```
from itertools import *
data_small = [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'] ]
data_big = [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['u','v','w'], ['x','y','z'] ]

def check(data, sub):
    check_for_mul_repl = []
    for i in data:
        if len(i) != len(data[0]):
            return False

        for j in i:
            if j in sub:
                if i.index(j) != sub.index(j):
                    return False
                else:
                    if i not in check_for_mul_repl:
                        check_for_mul_repl.append(i)
    if len(check_for_mul_repl) <= 2:
        return True
print [x for x in list(permutations(chain(*data_big), 3)) if check(data_big, x)]

['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'w'], ['a', 'b', 'z'],
['a', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'v', 'c'], ['a', 'v', 'w'],
['a', 'y', 'c'], ['a', 'y', 'z'], ['d', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'f'],
['d', 'e', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'w'], ['d', 'e', 'z'],
['d', 'v', 'f'], ['d', 'v', 'w'], ['d', 'y', 'f'], ['d', 'y', 'z'],
['u', 'b', 'c'], ['u', 'b', 'w'], ['u', 'e', 'f'], ['u', 'e', 'w'],
['u', 'v', 'c'], ['u', 'v', 'f'], ['u', 'v', 'w'], ['u', 'v', 'z'],
['u', 'y', 'w'], ['u', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'b', 'z'],
['x', 'e', 'f'], ['x', 'e', 'z'], ['x', 'v', 'w'], ['x', 'v', 'z'],
['x', 'y', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'f'], ['x', 'y', 'w'], ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

This doesn't care if there is more than one element being replaced

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

data_small = [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'] ]
data_big = [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['u','v','w'], ['x','y','z'] ]

def check(data, sub):
    for i in data:
        if len(i) != len(data[0]):
            return False

        for j in i:
            if j in sub:
                if i.index(j) != sub.index(j):
                    return False

    return True

#If you really want lists just change the first x to list(x)
print [x for x in list(permutations(chain(*data_big), 3)) if check(data_big, x)] 

['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'w'], 61 more...
```

The reason I use permutations instead of combinations is because `('d','b','c')` is equal to `('c','b','d')` in terms of combinations and not in permutations

If you just want combinations then that's a lot easier. You can just do

```
def check(data) #Check if all sub lists are same length
    for i in data:
        if len(i) != len(data[0]):
            return False
    return True

if check(data_small):
    print list(combinations(chain(*data_small), 3))

[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'f'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'f'), ('a', 'd', 'e'),
 ('a', 'd', 'f'), ('a', 'e', 'f'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'e'), 
 ('b', 'c', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'd', 'f'), ('b', 'e', 'f'),
 ('c', 'd', 'e'), ('c', 'd', 'f'), ('c', 'e', 'f'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late to the party, but here is the fancy "one--liner" (split over multiple lines for readability) using itertools and the extremely useful new Python 3.5 unpacking generalizations (which, by the way, is a significantly faster and more readable way of converting between iterable types than, say, calling `list` explicitly) --- and assuming unique elements:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, repeat, chain
>>> next([*map(lambda m: [m[i][i] for i in range(a)],
               {*permutations((*chain(*map(
                   repeat, map(tuple, l), repeat(a - 1))),), a)})]
         for l in ([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']],)
         for a in (len(l[0]),))
[['g', 'h', 'f'], ['g', 'b', 'i'], ['g', 'b', 'f'],
 ['d', 'b', 'f'], ['d', 'h', 'f'], ['d', 'h', 'i'],
 ['a', 'e', 'c'], ['g', 'e', 'i'], ['a', 'h', 'i'],
 ['a', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'i'],
 ['g', 'b', 'c'], ['g', 'h', 'c'], ['d', 'h', 'c'],
 ['d', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'f'],
 ['d', 'b', 'i'], ['a', 'h', 'c'], ['g', 'e', 'f'],
 ['a', 'e', 'i'], ['d', 'e', 'i'], ['a', 'h', 'f']]
```

The use of next on the generator and the last two lines are, of course, just unnecessary exploitations of syntax to put the expression into one line, and I hope people will not use this as an example of good coding practice.

**EDIT**
I just realised that maybe I should give a short explanation. So, the inner part creates `a - 1` copies of each sublist (converted to tuples for hashability and uniqueness testing) and chains them together to allow `permutations` to do its magic, which is to create all permutations of sublists of `a` sublists length. These are then converted to a set which gets rid of all duplicates which are bound to occur, and then a map pulls out the `i`th element of the `i`th sublist within each unique permutation. Finally, `a` is the length of the first sublist, since all sublists are assumed to have identical lengths.